# Pegar dados de um arquivo json pela url (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível pegar os dados desse json (http://destiny.trade/JSON/sortieRewards_f.json) sem baixa-lo. 
Atualmente eu consigo pegar os dados dele, mas eu gostaria de pegar através da url (quando houver algum update no json, pegar os dados automaticamente) 
O meu código está assim:
pagina index:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="dados.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Raridade</th>
                                <th>Drop Chance</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

pagina dados.js:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "name": "Rifle Riven Mod", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "6.79%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Ayatan Anasa Sculpture", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Uncommon", 
            "value": "28.00%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "4000 Endo", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Uncommon", 
            "value": "12.10%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Madurai Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.33%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Greater Madurai Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Legendary", 
            "value": "0.67%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Forma", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.50%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Exilus Adapter", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.50%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Orokin Reactor Blueprint", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.50%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Orokin Catalyst Blueprint", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.50%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Legendary Core", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Legendary", 
            "value": "0.18%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Vazarin Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.33%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Zenurik Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.33%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Naramon Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.33%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Unairu Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "2.33%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Greater Vazarin Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Legendary", 
            "value": "0.67%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Greater Zenurik Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Legendary", 
            "value": "0.67%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Greater Naramon Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Legendary", 
            "value": "0.67%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Greater Unairu Lens", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Legendary", 
            "value": "0.67%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Credit Booster", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "3.27%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Affinity Booster", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "3.27%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Resource Drop Chance Booster", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "3.27%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Pistol Riven Mod", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "7.61%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Shotgun Riven Mod", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Ultra Rare", 
            "value": "1.36%"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Melee Riven Mod", 
        "rarity": {
            "name": "Rare", 
            "value": "9.14%"
        }
    }
];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "info": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            data: data,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "rarity.name"},
                { "data": "rarity.value"}
            ]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Como tu já usas `jQuery` podes usar uma função que é `jQuery.getJson()`

**Exemplo:**

```
$.getJSON(url, function(result){
  // result é o json obtido
});
```

**Prática:**

```
$.getJSON("http://destiny.trade/JSON/sortieRewards_f.json", function(result){
  // result, é o seu "data"
});
```

Comment: ta dando "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://destiny.trade/JSON/sortieRewards_f.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: A solução desse erro tá [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)   Eu não consigo explicar por comentário como resolver e tambêm seria complicado mas tá [ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)